# The pokédex that I can't continue

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am a beginner. I'm trying to display information about my Pokemon when I click on them.

Once I click on Pikachu, for example, I would like its index, image front, image back, and name.

Where is the problem? Because I have already created a click event, but it's not working.

My code does not work as expected because when clicked, nothing is displayed. So I should have this information: index, image front, image back, and name.

I just opened my console (I hadn't done it before, thank you for letting me know) and it shows me this:

```
index.html:112 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: ceil is not defined
     at index.html:112:9
```

In the debugger it shows me the same thing.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Pokédex</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='grid'>

    </div>
    <div id="grid2"></div>
</body>
</html>

<style>
    #grid2
    {
        display: none;
    }
    .item{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        border: solid;
    }
    #grid{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
        gap: 10px;
    }
</style>
<script>
    //Crée une constante grid qui stocke l’élément HTML avec l’ID grid. Cet élément est utilisé plus tard pour ajouter des éléments à la page.
    const grid = document.getElementById('grid')

    //Envoie une requête à l’API PokeAPI pour récupérer les 151 premiers Pokémon. La méthode fetch() renvoie une promesse qui sera résolue lorsque la réponse sera reçue.
    fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=151')
    //Utilise la méthode then() pour extraire les données JSON de la réponse de l’API. La méthode json() renvoie également une promesse.
    .then(response => response.json())
    //Utilise la méthode then() pour accéder aux données JSON extraites de la réponse de l’API.
    .then(data => {
        //Crée une constante results qui stocke les résultats de la requête API sous forme d’un tableau d’objets Pokémon.
        const results = data.results
        // Utilise la méthode forEach() pour parcourir chaque objet Pokémon dans le tableau results. La méthode forEach() prend une fonction de rappel qui est appelée pour chaque élément du tableau.
        results.forEach((pokemon, index) => {
            // Crée un nouvel élément HTML <div> qui sera utilisé pour afficher les informations sur chaque Pokémon.
            const ceil = document.createElement('div')
            // Ajoute la classe item au nouvel élément HTML <div>.
            ceil.classList.add('item')
            // Crée une constante pokemonNumber qui stocke le numéro du Pokémon actuel dans le tableau, en incrémentant l’index de 1.
            const pokemonNumber = ++index

            // Crée un nouvel élément HTML <img> qui sera utilisé pour afficher l’image du Pokémon.
            const img = document.createElement('img')
            //Définit l’attribut src de l’élément <img> créé précédemment en utilisant le numéro du Pokémon actuel dans le tableau.
            img.src=`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/${pokemonNumber}.png`
            // Crée un nouvel élément HTML <div> qui sera utilisé pour afficher le nom du Pokémon.
            const name = document.createElement('div')
            // Crée une constante pokemonName qui stocke le nom du Pokémon actuel dans le tableau.
            const pokemonName = pokemon.name
            // Définit le texte interne de l’élément <div> créé précédemment en utilisant le nom du Pokémon actuel dans le tableau.
            name.innerText = pokemonName
            // Ajoute l’élément <img> créé précédemment à l’élément <div> créé précédemment.
            ceil.appendChild(img)
            // Ajoute l’élément <div> créé précédemment contenant le nom du Pokémon à l’élément <div> créé précédemment.
            ceil.appendChild(name)
            // Ajoute l’élément <div> créé précédemment contenant toutes les informations sur le Pokémon à la page HTML, en l’ajoutant comme enfant de l’élément avec l’ID 'grid'.
            grid.appendChild(ceil)
        })
        

        // Ajoute un gestionnaire d'événements onclick à chaque élément de la grille
        ceil.onclick = function() {
            fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemonNumber}`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(`Index: ${pokemonNumber}`)
                console.log(`Image Front: ${data.sprites.front_default}`)
                console.log(`Image Back: ${data.sprites.back_default}`)
                console.log(`Name: ${data.name}`)
            })
        }
    }) 
</script>
```

Here is the site where I get the APIs : https://pokeapi.co/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Additionally... If you're not familiar with your browser's development tools (e.g. F12 in Chrome) then now is a great time to start.  With those tools you can observe the current state of the HTML, observe the console for any warnings or errors, observe network requests and responses, and use the script debugger to step through the code and observe its behavior.  When you do this, what do you find?

Comment: THANKS ! My code does not work as expected because when clicked, nothing is displayed. So I should have this information: Index, Image Front, Image Back, and Name.

I just opened my console (I hadn't done it before, thank you for letting me know) and it shows me this:

index.html:112 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: ceil is not defined
     at index.html:112:9

In the debugger it shows me the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ceil.onclick = function()` is currently outside the `result.forEach`, therefore the `ceil is not defined` error is thrown.

Move that assignment inside the loop, before you `append` the new `ceil` element

```js
const grid = document.getElementById('grid')

fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=151')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
    const results = data.results
    results.forEach((pokemon, index) => {
        const ceil = document.createElement('div')
        ceil.classList.add('item')
        const pokemonNumber = ++index

        ceil.onclick = function() {
            fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemonNumber}`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(`Index: ${pokemonNumber}`)
                console.log(`Image Front: ${data.sprites.front_default}`)
                console.log(`Image Back: ${data.sprites.back_default}`)
                console.log(`Name: ${data.name}`)
            })
        }
        
        const img = document.createElement('img')
        //Définit l’attribut src de l’élément <img> créé précédemment en utilisant le numéro du Pokémon actuel dans le tableau.
        img.src=`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/${pokemonNumber}.png`
        const name = document.createElement('div')
        const pokemonName = pokemon.name
        name.innerText = pokemonName
        ceil.appendChild(img)
        ceil.appendChild(name)
        grid.appendChild(ceil)
    })


})
```

```css
#grid2 {
    display: none;
}
.item{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    border: solid;
}
#grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
    gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id='grid'>

</div>
<div id="grid2"></div>
```